# ¿Como no seleccionar mas de 1 checkbox, jquery?

Tags: jquery

Tengo la siguiente validación:

```
var contador = 0;

if (contador>0){
           console.log("no se puede seleccionar mas checkbox");
           $(this).removeAttr('checked');
           console.log(contador);
        }
        else{
            if ($(this).is(':checked')){
                console.log("Esta chequeado");
                console.log(numero_prestamo);

               /* prestamo_seleccionado.NumeroDocumento = 
                prestamo_seleccionado.Monto = 
                prestamo_seleccionado.Tipo_Prestamo =
                prestamo_seleccionado.NumeroPrestamo =
                prestamo_seleccionado.Cod_Fiador = */
                contador++;
                console.log(contador);
            }
            else{
                console.log("No esta chequeado");
                prestamo_seleccionado = {};
                contador--;
                console.log(contador);

            }
        }
```

y basicamente lo que necesito hacer es que no me permita seleccionar mas de 1 checkbox.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Podrías mostrar tu `html`, y tmb poner completo tu evento del `checkbox`?

Comment: Para que no se pueda seleccionar más de un checkbox es muy simple. Le pones a todos el mismo `name`, con eso el checkbox se comportará de su forma natural.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te agrego un `html` de ejemplo, en la siguiente función se evalúan todas las casillas de aquellos que sean tipo `checkbox`, se utiliza el `.prop` para obtener el valor de la primer coincidencia que encuentre (en este caso establece la propiedad "checked"):

```js
$("input:checkbox").on('click', function() {
  var box = $(this);
  if (box.is(":checked")) {
    var group = "input:checkbox[name='" + box.attr("name") + "']";
    $(group).prop("checked", false);
    box.prop("checked", true);
  } else {
    box.prop("checked", false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <h3>Frutas</h3>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="radio" value="1" name="fooby[1][]" />Manzana</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="radio" value="1" name="fooby[1][]" />Naranja</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="radio" value="1" name="fooby[1][]" />Mango</label>
</div>
```

Espero te ayude. Saludos.